# Manipulations within sliding window functions (for image denoising)

Tags: python, image, matlab, sliding-window

I'm working on image de-noising, trying to keep continuous lines (with some leniency) in my matrix and removing random non-zero elements which are not really connected to the lines I'm after. The problem I have is detailed below:

I have tried to write a sliding window function that will search through row `r` of my 2-D matrix and look for non-zero digits.
For each non-zero digit, the function should look for the presence of a non-zero element within the `2x2` neighbourhood (2 numbers either side of the non-zero element) of row `r` and of row `r+1` (and `r-1` if it exists).
If the neighbourhood is empty, that original element in row `r` should be zeroed, otherwise all non-zero elements within the window should be kept.
To complicate things, I am also trying to make the sliding window circular, so that when it reaches the end of the row, it doesn't get compressed, but rather includes numbers from the start of the row in the neighbourhood.

For all rows, I can also only keep a "connected" element, if it is in some way connected to row 1, so continuous lines down my matrix cannot start in row 2.

I've written this with `for`-loops in Matlab, and ran into problems when trying to manipulate values within the window. Aside from that, my function is really slow. Is there a way to do this in Matlab or Python without using `for`-loops, and without any pre-installed toolboxes?

Sample Matlab Code: "test" is a binary matrix (but not all matrices I'll look at will be binary). It contains 5 rows. This is dummy code I wrote for row 1. The window manipulation (line 4 of the code) doesn't work, but hopefully this will give you some idea of what I'm trying to do. This code also omits the edges of the matrix as I wasn't sure the best way to make this circular.

```
n=2 % size of neighborhood to look at
p=size(test,2) % length of row

for ii=1+n:p-n;
    if test(1,ii)==1;
        if sum(test(2,(ii-2:ii+2))+test(1,(ii-2:ii+2)))>=2;
           test(2,(ii-2:ii+2))=test(2,(ii-2:ii+2))*2;
        else;
           test(1,ii)=0;
        end;
    end;
end

var=test(2,:);
var(var==1)=0;
var(var>=2)=1;
test(2,:)=var;

Example matrix ("test"): (zeros replaced with '.' for better visualization)

. . . 1 . . 1 . . . . 1 1 1 . . . . . . . 
1 . . . 1 . 1 . . . 1 . . . . . . . . 1 .
. . . . . 1 1 1 . . . 1 . . . . . . 1 . .
. . 1 . . . . . 1 . . . . . . . . . . 1 .
. . . . . . . . . 1 . . . . . 1 . . . . .

Desired output: (zeros replaced with '.' for better visualization)

. . . 1 . . 1 . . . . 1 1 1 . . . . . . .
. . . . 1 . 1 . . . 1 . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . 1 1 1 . . . 1 . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . 1 . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . 1 . . . . . . . . . . .
```

Comment: I'm having trouble visualizing the neighborhoods you're using. A sample matrix would help.

Comment: Welcome! You'll stand a better chance of getting help, when you illustrate your question with your code.

Comment: When you choose to share your code, **do not** post it as a comment but edit your question.

Comment: Do you have the image processing toolbox by the way? I am forseeing some bwmorph and other logical operators being pretty useful here.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. Schorsch, I've edited the question to try and make things clearer. Shaun314, I do not have the image processing toolbox unfortunately. I wonder whether it's better to write this in python?

Comment: I could get the image processing toolbox, but this function will form part of a larger piece of code which I'm hoping to make open-source, and some users might not have the image processing toolbox...

Comment: Are you sure you want to modify the matrix in-place, or do you want to test the original values and write to a result matrix? Because by the time you get to the second row it's probable that several of the values will be > 1.

Comment: I think you're right that's its better to write the output to a result matrix - the general idea is to try and keep the numbers in row r+1 that were identified in the window from row r - all other numbers should be set to zero. The test matrix is binary, so had planned to multiply all values, within the window, to keep by 2 and set all other random ones to zero later... this obviously won't work for a non-binary matrix though...

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence at all. I still think that sample (non-binary) matrices with more than two rows and the expected results would help tremendously. For example, what would you expect from an input matrix of [0 0 5 0 0; 4 2 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 9]? (Note that you can make the rows circular by padding them with the values with the opposite end of the row resulting in a working matrix of [0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0; 0 0 4 2 0 0 0 4 2; 0 9 0 0 0 0 9 0 0].) What if the 9 is changed to a 0?

Comment: Hi beaker,
Sorry for the confusion. The desired answer for your padded matrix should be: [0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0; 0 0 4 2 0 0 0 0 0; 0 9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
and for the unpadded matrix [0 0 5 0 0; 4 2 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0]. I have also added an example to the main question of the type of binary matrix I wrote the dummy code for. My comment was to say that the code I wrote (i.e. multiplying by 2) would only work for the binary example, not for non-binary. Hope that clears things up and thanks for your help!

Comment: i.e. I would replace all numbers >1 with 1 and everything =1 with 0 in row2 before restarting the dummy code for row 2.

Comment: First, the desired matrix that you wrote in the question cannot be the output of your source because of the multiplying by 2 in the end of line 4 of the loop. so i didn't realy understand what do you want to get. Second, the non-binary has a problem in the second "if" condition, that you required that will be big or equal to 2. That's why it works only on binary matrix

Comment: Hi, just edited the code - new to this site so still learning! I tried to explain the conversion of 2s to 1s earlier, but should have added it to the code. I was trying to say that I'd like to get to a non-binary solution, but tried with the binary first for simplicity... the code I wrote above will not work for the non-binary matrix as you said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an outline to do what I *think* you're trying to do:

#### Step 1:

Find all of the matrix positions that have non-zero elements in their 3x5 neighborhood by summing the values of the neighbors. We don't want to include the current element just yet, hence the zero in the  middle. Input matrix is `test`.

```
fil = [1 1 1 1 1; 1 1 0 1 1; 1 1 1 1 1];
A = conv2(test, fil, 'same');
```

#### Step 2:

`A` now contains values > 1, so change them all to 1, leaving the zero values alone.

```
A(A > 0) = 1;
```

#### Step 3:

Now that you've identified all of elements with valid neighborhoods, combine `test` with `A` by element-wise multiplication leaving only those elements that are both non-zero in `test` **and** have non-zero neighbors.

```
result = test .* A;
```

#### Step 0:

Padding - The above should work as is, but pads both rows and columns with zeros. As I understand them, your padding requirements are that you want circular rows and the columns padded with zeros.

```
nCols = size(test, 2);
paddedTest = [zeros(1,nCols);...
              test(:, nCols-1:nCols), test, test(:,1:2);...
              zeros(1,nCols)];
```

This obviously changes the size of the matrix you're working on by doing your own padding, so you need to change the convolution parameters in order to return a matrix the same size as `test`.

```
A = conv2(paddedTest, fil, 'valid');
```

I don't have Matlab available right now to test this, but hopefully others will correct any egregious errors I've made.